# How can I replace symbols from the query prop on Elastic UI search bar?

Tags: reactjs, elasticui

I have searched all through the documentation and I can’t seem to find how I can replace any symbols in the query prop string passed by the EUI search bar to an on change prop. Here’s the documentation.

https://elastic.github.io/eui/#/tabular-content/in-memory-tables

Any symbols seem to cause a null value error when trying to use the prop so even if I do a .replace in the onchange function it returns null.